# Restricting access to just CVS and Git commands

Tags: git, account-restrictions, oracle-linux, cvs

At work we have a server which hosts our CVS repository and in order to restrict shell access to this system, I have deployed [rssh](http://www.pizzashack.org/rssh/) which has worked well for a number of years.

We are now converting part of our repository to Git and using this existing server to host a centralized bare Git repository. I would like to extend these restrictions to Git commands as well, but `rssh` does not support Git. I know that Git has [git-shell](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-shell.html) which does a similar thing for Git (though I haven't used it) but I don't think it understands CVS.

Given that both approaches use the mechanism of setting the user's shell to one of these, I can't use them both at the same time.

We still need to use the CVS repository so **is there any mechanism that would work for both CVS and Git?**

My options at the moment are:

- Do nothing (not really an option).
- Find a way to make them both work (hence this question).
- Forget security and just give everyone shell access.
- Abandon the idea and put the central Git repository on another server (probably virtual) and use `git-shell`.
- Something else which I haven't thought of.

Comment: Just an idea, but what if you used 2 different users? You typically see things like `git@gitserver.com` as the frontend user when interacting with the repo. The other technology that might be useful is to use `command=` in your SSH's `$HOME/.ssh/authorized_keys` file.

Comment: cvs uses OS user names to identify committers and so I would never have thought of using a single account for git. It's an interesting idea. Is that seen as good practise? The idea of using a single account for multiple people makes me wary.

Comment: @BurhanAli You wouldn't use the same account for multiple people. slm's first idea is to use one account per person per service, so 2 accounts per person.

Comment: Oh, I guess I misunderstood then. Two accounts for each person would be very annoying for everyone involved. I guess I also don't understand what is meant by "You typically see things like git@gitserver.com as the frontend user when interacting with the repo." I interpreted that line as one account used by all.

Comment: @Gilles Actually, I have been reading ["Git on the Server - Setting Up the Server"](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-on-the-Server-Setting-Up-the-Server) and it *is* suggesting using a single user (called `git`) for all users. So my concerns about using a single account are still there.

Comment: @BurhanAli - I meant to use 2 users, 1 for git, and 1 for subversion. Typically I've seen Git servers setup so that there's a single `git@gitserver.com` and you interact with this sever using SSH key pairs, so that the server identifies the user through the use of a particular set of keys.